How to interpret the following pix2pix training losses?
The plots of loss functions obtained are as follows:
enter image description here
How to interpret this graph? I don't know this results is great or bad..
How to improve this pix2pix model?
Help me please.
epoch : 800
batch size : 16
learning rate : 0.0001
